# Can't invoke g++ with redirected stdout

Tags: c++, gcc

I'm looking to invoke g++ and get the output. Here's my code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

namespace Util
{
    template<typename T>
    using optional = boost::optional<T>;
}

namespace Wide
{
    namespace Driver
    {
        struct ProcessResult
        {
            std::string std_out;
            int exitcode;
        };

        ProcessResult StartAndWaitForProcess(std::string name, std::vector<std::string> args, Util::optional<unsigned> timeout);
    }
}

#include <unistd.h>    
#include <sys/types.h>    
#include <sys/wait.h> 
#include <iostream>
#include <fcntl.h>
Wide::Driver::ProcessResult Wide::Driver::StartAndWaitForProcess(std::string name, std::vector<std::string> args, Util::optional<unsigned> timeout) {
    int filedes[2];
    pipe(filedes);
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        while ((dup2(filedes[1], STDOUT_FILENO) == -1) && (errno == EINTR)) {}
        auto fd = open("/dev/null", O_RDWR);
        while ((dup2(fd, STDIN_FILENO) == -1) && (errno == EINTR)) {}
        //freopen("/dev/null", "rw", stdin);
        //freopen("/dev/null", "rw", stderr);
        //close(filedes[1]);
        close(filedes[0]);
        std::vector<const char*> cargs;
        cargs.push_back(name.c_str());
        for (auto&& arg : args)
            cargs.push_back(arg.c_str());
        cargs.push_back(nullptr);
        execv(name.c_str(), const_cast<char* const*>(&cargs[0]));
    }
    std::string std_out;
    close(filedes[1]);
    char buffer[4096];
    while (1) {
        ssize_t count = read(filedes[0], buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        if (count == -1) {
            if (errno == EINTR) {
                continue;
            } else {
                perror("read");
                exit(1);
            }
        } else if (count == 0) {
            break;
        } else {
            std_out += std::string(buffer, buffer + count);
        }
    }
    close(filedes[0]);
    int status;
    ProcessResult result;
    result.std_out = std_out;
    waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
    if (!WIFEXITED(status))
        result.exitcode = 1;
    else {
        result.exitcode = WEXITSTATUS(status);
        if (result.exitcode != 0) {
            std::cout << name << " failed with code " << result.exitcode << "\n";
        }
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    auto r = Wide::Driver::StartAndWaitForProcess("g++", { "-std=c++14", "main.cpp" }, 150);
    std::cout << r.std_out << "!!!!\n!!!!\n" << r.exitcode << "\n";
}
```

The output:

```
read: Bad file descriptor
g++ failed with code 1
!!!!
!!!!
1
```

Just invoke `g++ main.cpp -std=c++14 && ./a.out`.

I've used strace but it doesn't really give any more interesting details- the process runs, then fork/exec, then the above error. I can invoke other processes with the above code so I don't know what's so different about `g++`. I can invoke GCC with `popen` without problems so I don't know what's so different here.

The error here is really not very helpful. How can I invoke `g++` and get the output?

Comment: I think you want to use `execvp` instead of `execv`. Either that, or use `/full/path/to/gcc`

Comment: Good shout. If nothing else, I should throw if exec failed.

Comment: execvp did the trick. Post as answer so I can upvote + accept

Comment: OK, posted as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you call [`execv`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html) which requires a full path to the executable as its first argument.

What you need is `execvp` which uses the contents of the `PATH` environment variable to find the executable, and thus only requires a name like `g++`.